# Add html with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a agenda system with weeks but I want an option that can make the user add as much weeks as he wants

html

```
    <h1>Agenda</h1>

    <div class="balkje dicht">
      <h2>WEEK 1</h2>
      <div>
        <div class="col1"><p>Hier staat meer informatie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore </p></div>
        <div class="col2"><p>et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p></div>
        <div class="col3"><p>consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div> 
        <form>
          <input class="stop" type="text">
          <input id="btnsubmit" class="stop" type="submit"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div> <!--end -->

    <div class="balkje dicht">
      <h2>WEEK 2</h2>
      <p >Hier staat meer informatie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="balkje dicht">
      <h2>WEEK 3</h2>
      <p>Hier staat meer informatie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

for jquery I have

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".balkje").on("click", function(event) {
      $(this).stop(true, true).toggleClass('open dicht', 250);
    });

    $(".stop").on("click", function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
  })
```

css
http://pastebin.com/17UEgk4b

now I was wondering if it's possible to make an input field as example add 2 weeks en then instead of 3 weeks there would be 5

thanks

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/append/ or https://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: I was able to add a new element but it seems like the jquery to open or close it doesn't work on the added element

Comment: You need to delegate events, e.g: `$(document).on('click', '.balkje', function(event){...});` and same way for `.stop` elements. See: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify a bit your html to this :

```
<h1>Agenda</h1>
<form id="addWeek" action="#">
    <input class="stop" type="text"/>
    <input id="btnsubmit" class="stop" type="submit"/>
</form>

<div id="weeks">

    <div class="balkje dicht">
        <h2>WEEK 1</h2>
        <div>
            <div class="col1"><p>Hier staat meer informatie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore </p></div>
            <div class="col2"><p>et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p></div>
            <div class="col3"><p>consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div> 

        </div>
    </div> <!--end -->

    <div class="balkje dicht">
        <h2>WEEK 2</h2>
        <p >Hier staat meer informatie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- [...] -->

</div>
```

and put some JQuery :

```
$("#addWeek").submit(function() {
    var iter = $(this).find(".stop").val();
    for (var i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        $("#weeks").append("<div class=\"balkje dicht\">\
    <h2>WEEK</h2>\
    <div>\
        <div class=\"col1\"><p>Hier staat meer informatie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore </p></div>\
        <div class=\"col2\"><p>et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p></div>\
        <div class=\"col3\"><p>consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>\
    </div>\
</div>");
    }
});
```

DEMO [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUHf8/)

Comment: You'll have to adapt it if you want the number of the week.